# How to get clientID if textbox name is in string variable

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have written below code to check for blank value in my textbox but its generating compilation Error, please provide me solution.

my code in javascript:

```
 function checkTextboxNotFilled(txtbox) {
        var txtb = document.getElementById("<%= " + txtbox + ".ClientID %>");
        if (GetFormattedString(txtb.value) == "") {
            return true ;
        }
        else {
            return false ;
        }
    }
```

error:

```
'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am calling it like this : checkTextboxNotFilled("MytextboxName")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be helpful to you.

```
 function checkTextboxNotFilled(txtboxid) {
        var txtb = document.getElementById(txtboxid);
        if (GetFormattedString(txtb.value) == "") {
            return true ;
        }
        else {
            return false ;
        }
    }
```

and call : `checkTextboxNotFilled("<%= Mytextbox.ClientID %>");`

Comment: Thanks Bro, Its working now. but is their any way to get clientid if textbox name is in string format..?

Comment: Nope. That way you will get the error. I think you should go this way only.